# log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger / Please initialize the log4j system properly while executing tests through Selenium in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, logging

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Answer (score 1):

This log messages...

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies). 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

...implies that the following:

- **log4j** *JARs* were downloaded and added to the *Java Build Path* of this project.
- `log4j.properties` file was created.
- Both of the above items was used by a program/script with in the same *Project Space*.

### Reason

As in your current *Java* program/file you havn't initialized/handled the **log4j** configuration properly hence you see those *WARNINGS*.

### Conclusion

These *WARN* messages are harmless and doesn't impact your tests and you can live with it.